# failed to find target Vuzix Corporation:Vuzix M300 SDK:23

Tags: android, vuzixm100

I am trying to develop an app for Vuzix M300 smartglasses.
I have installed Vuzix SDK by Android SDK Manager. I have followed all the steps as mentioned by Vuzix documentation. 
I have also set the compile SDK version to Vuzix M300 SDK.
but still, I am getting the error as

```
"Error:failed to find target Vuzix Corporation:Vuzix M300 SDK:23 : C:\Users\..MyName..\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>"
```

But Android SDK Manager shows that the Vuzix SDK is already installed.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution working for me. You must install also `Android SDK Platform 23` (and corresponding Tools but Android Studio will take care of this). Then do `File -> Invalidate cache/Restart`. After this Gradle compiled project without errors.

[image: Android SDK Platform 23]