# I found the following error during vuzix m100 setting in android studio

Tags: android, vuzix

The error contents are as follows.

```
failed to find target Vuzix Corporation:Vuzix M100 Add-On:15 : C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

[I installed vuzix m100 sdk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xINs5.png) But I don't know why the problem arises.

Please Help me Please.
It is very eager.

Comment: Have you seen this, might be helpful; https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864009/476747